# Multiple column filter flexibility in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datagridview

I have multiple text boxes so that the user has flexibility to select filtering options of Datagrid(e.g Aggregate(txtbox),Branch(comboxbox),Gender(comboxbox),Semester I marks etc).
User can filter single or multiple columns based on the input given to the textbox.
I am able to filter single or multiple columns but the problem i am facing is that code becomes too lengthy(specially if else statement)

eg:

if user user enters data in aggregate and branch field the code changes....likewise if user user enters data in aggregate,branch and gender field the code changes and so on.
i have 8 filtering options so it is not feasible to write if else statement for all combinations.

```
   if (textBox1.Text != "" && comboBox1.Text!="")
        {
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
                bs.Filter = "[Aggregate]>='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND [Branch]='" + comboBox1.Text+ "'";
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
         }
```

Like the above code i have to write it for all combinations...so is there any correct approach?
Pls do help...Thank you

Comment: User has the freedom to select any filtering options....so it is not necessary to enter all the filtering data in various textbox